# Reason for using generally TH type current sense resistors in SMPS circuits

Tags: power-supply, resistors, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm investigating SMPS circuits and I'm trying to design my own.

In my design, I have a 300mOhm current sense resistor and its power rating must be minimum 177mW so I need a 500mW resistor. I have chosen a 2512 SMD package 1W resistor for it.

When I investigated other SMPS circuits that have same specifications (same output wattage & voltage) I noticed that they have through hole type resistors. Is there a reason for it or any reason to avoid using SMD type current sense resistors?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be fair, all the other components are through hole.  So your comparision is not valid.

Comment: Not all components are th. Pcbs have bottom side and there are a lots of smd components (pwm controller ic. Etc.)

Comment: PCB real estate would be one.

Comment: OK, there are surface mount components, but this probably has more to do with parts not available in through hole packages.

Answer (score 3):

One reason is probably that the surge power capability of larger resistors, especially wire-wound ones, is much better than surface mount resistors. It mainly relates to the thermal capacity of the resistor - large is better in general.

In this application a surge may occur is the supply is shorted, before the current limiting comes into effect.

Your choice of a 2512 2W resistor does seem to be a good one though with a good pulse load capability.

[image: https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/crm-a.pdf?sfvrsn=353a74f6_13]
[Bourns Thick film resistor](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/crm-a.pdf?sfvrsn=353a74f6_13)
[11 things you need to know about resistors in pulse load applications](https://www.planetanalog.com/11-things-you-need-to-know-about-resistors-in-pulse-load-applications/)